# Can you bring an electric scooter on Flixbus?

Tags: luggage, prohibited-items, flixbus, electric-kickbikes

Is it possible to bring an electric kickbike on Flixbus? The luggage limit is all sides combined 160 cm and max. 20 kg. I think an average electric kickbike would fit that.

If it's not possible to bring it as normal luggage, can one bring it as special luggage?

I also noted at electric bicycles aren't allow on the bicycle stand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer below is no longer valid as FlixBus has changed their carriage conditions and no longer allows e-scooters.

---

According to the [Terms and Conditions of Carriage](https://global.flixbus.com/terms-and-conditions-of-carriage),

> 15.7.2.1 E-scooters are considered **special baggage**, which means they are subject to the size and weight restrictions of a special baggage (c.f. clause 15.3.2) and are carried in the baggage compartment **for an additional fee** (c.f. clause 15.3.5). For transportation, the e-scooter must be **folded up and packed in a suitable bag**.

Other relevant provisions:

> 15.3.1 So-called special baggage **requires prior registration** by passengers and confirmation that its carriage is possible. No general claim to the carriage of special baggage shall exist.
>
> 15.3.2 Items that exceed the standard baggage dimensions are considered special baggage. However, the overall dimensions of special baggage items **may not exceed 240 cm (height in cm + width in cm + depth in cm)**. A single item of special baggage may not exceed **a maximum weight of 30 kg**.
>
> 15.3.3 The carriage of special baggage shall be limited to **one item per passenger**.
>
> ...
>
> 15.3.5 Special baggage **must be registered in advance**, either (if it is possible for the trip) via the booking system or by telephone, at the
> earliest 48 hours before the start of the trip, via the following
> hotlines:
>
> ```
> Calls from Germany and Switzerland (German landline): +49 30 300 137 300
> Calls from Austria (Austrian landline): +43 820 910 340
> Calls from Italy (Italian landline): +39 (02) 947 59 208
> Calls from France (French landline): +33 (0)1 76 36 04 12
> Calls from Great Britain (British landline): +44 1 78 82 98 784
> Calls from Croatia (Croatian landline): +385 1 800 03 80
> Calls from Denmark (Danish landline): +45 32 72 93 86
> Calls from Sweden (Swedish landline): +46 850513750
> Calls from Poland (Polish landline): +48 22 307 93 34*
> Calls from Russia (Russian landline): +7 (495) 283-97-30
> ```
>
> If special baggage is transported, an additional baggage fee per item
> will be charged. The [fee for a special baggage](https://global.flixbus.com/company/prices/special-baggage) is regardless of the
> length and ticket price of the route booked. The transportation of
> special baggage, in contrast to normal baggage, is always subject to a
> charge.

Comment: Seems they no longer allow e-scooters `15.7.2.1 The carriage of e-scooters in long-distance buses is excluded in principle.`.